# Python function not accessing class variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to access a class variable in an outside function, however I get the AttributeError, "Class has no attribute"  My codes looks something like this:

```
class example():
     def __init__():
          self.somevariable = raw_input("Input something: ")

def notaclass():
    print example.somevariable

AttributeError: class example has no attribute 'somevariable'
```

Other questions have been asked similar to this however all the answers said to use self and define during **init**, which I did.  Why can't I access this variable.

Comment: `self.somevariable` is an instance variable, not a class variable.

Comment: To understand this, you have to realize that the `example` class is an object, but it's of type `type`, not of type `example`. Each _instance_ of the `example` class that you create with, e.g., `inst = example()` is an object of type `example`. Your code creates a `somevariable` attribute in each object of type `example`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to create a class variable, you must to declare it outside any class methods (but still inside the class definition):

```
class Example(object):
      somevariable = 'class variable'
```

With this you can now access your class variable.

```
>> Example.somevariable
'class variable'
```

---

The reason why your example isn't working is because you are assigning a value to an `instance` variable.

The difference between the two is that a `class` variable is created as soon as the class object is created. Whereas an `instance` variable will be created once the object has been *instantiated* and only after they have been assigned to.

```
class Example(object):
      def doSomething(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
```

Here we created an instance of `Example`, however if we try to access `othervariable` we will get an error:

```
>> foo.othervariable
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'othervariable'
```

Since `othervariable` is assigned inside `doSomething` - and we haven't called ityet -, it does not exist.

```
>> foo.doSomething()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

---

`__init__` is a special method that automatically gets invoked whenever class instantiation happens.

```
class Example(object):

      def __init__(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you, Carlos!

Answer (score 14):

You're a bit confused on what is a class attribute, and what is not.

```
  class aclass(object):
      # This is a class attribute.
      somevar1 = 'a value'

      def __init__(self):
          # this is an instance variable.
          self.somevar2 = 'another value'

      @classmethod
      def usefulfunc(cls, *args):
          # This is a class method.
          print(cls.somevar1) # would print 'a value'

      def instancefunc(self, *args):
          # this is an instance method.
          print(self.somevar2) # would print 'another value'

  aclass.usefulfunc()
  inst = aclass()
  inst.instancefunc()
```

The class variables are always accessible from the class:

```
print(aclass.somevar1) # prints 'a value'
```

Likewise, all instances have access to all instance variables:

```
print(inst.somevar2) # prints 'another value'
```

Comment: You might also want to show that `aclass.somevar1` and `inst.somevar2` work on their own.