# Why it can't find a object in class (python)

Tags: python

```
class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):    
        self.packer = MessagePacker.MessagePacker()
        self.parser = MessageParser.MessageParser()

    def handle(self):        
        self.setup()
        while True:
            pass
            #blabla...

class FroggerServer(threading.Thread):
    def init(self,ip,nickname):
        self.serverIp = ip
        self.serverPort = 10000
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.tcpHandler = TCPHandler
        tuple = (self.serverIp,self.serverPort)               
        self.__serverSocket = socketserver.TCPServer(tulpe,self.tcpHandler)

    def run(self):
        self.__serverSocket.serve_forever()
```

I used socket and then decleard TCPHandler.
The problem is can't find a 'packer', 'parser' in TCPHandler.

For eaxmple, like this.

```
server = FroggerServer()
server.init(ip,nickname)
server.start()
server.parser.putMessage(43)  #oops. not exist object parser in server object
```

I thought there is matter in `self.tcpHandler = TCPHandler` if I dont use this way, How can I access objects in TCPHandler at outer of this class

Comment: `server` does not have a `parser` attribute. `sever` does have a `tcpHandler` attribute which you probably want to use.

Comment: server.tcpHandler.parser.putMessage(43) will work but @WasiAhmad answer below is best for you.

Comment: first I fixed 'self.tcpHandler = TCPHandler' to 'self.tcpHandler = TCPHandler()'. and then I put the constructor as your say. thansk your comments (_ _)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):    
        self.packer = MessagePacker.MessagePacker()
        self.parser = MessageParser.MessageParser()

    def handle(self):        
        self.setup()
        # your code

    def getPacker():
        return self.packer

    def getParser():
        return self.parser

class FroggerServer(threading.Thread):
    def init(self,ip,nickname):
        # your code

    def run(self):
        self.__serverSocket.serve_forever()

    def getTCPHandler():
        return self. tcpHandler
```

Then you can do:

```
server = FroggerServer()
server.init(ip,nickname)
server.start()
server.getTCPHandler().getParser().putMessage(43)
```

---

**Alternative approach**: You can do the following as well.

```
class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):    
        self.packer = MessagePacker.MessagePacker()
        self.parser = MessageParser.MessageParser()

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            pass
            #blabla...

class FroggerServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, nickname):
        self.serverIp = ip
        self.serverPort = 10000
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.tcpHandler = TCPHandler()
        tuple = (self.serverIp, self.serverPort)               
        self.__serverSocket = socketserver.TCPServer(tulpe, self.tcpHandler)

    def run(self):
        self.__serverSocket.serve_forever()
```

Now create your server object as follows. You can now access the variable `parser` of `TCPHandler` class.

```
server = FroggerServer(ip, nickname)
server.start()
server.tcpHandler.parser.putMessage(43)
```

---

> Why the above will work?

Suppose, you have the following class.

```
class Example(object):
      def doSomething(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
```

Here we created an instance of `Example`, however if we try to access `othervariable` we will get an error:

```
>> foo.othervariable
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'othervariable'
```

Since `othervariable` is assigned inside `doSomething` and we haven't called it yet, it does not exist.

```
>> foo.doSomething()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

Please note, `__init__` is a special method that automatically gets invoked whenever class instantiation happens.

```
class Example(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680307/5352399