# Why can't I access an class variable defined in __init__ from outside of the class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes

I was wondering about classes and how I can access their values from the outside with either printing it or using the _str__ function. I came across this question:
[Python function not accessing class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680221/python-function-not-accessing-class-variable)

Then I did this test in Shell, but it didn't work as expected. I wonder why the other answer worked, but not this one.

(edit)
My question was answered by how to instantiate a class, not instance variables.

```
>>> class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testy=0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.testy


>>> a=test
>>> b=test
>>> print(a)
<class '__main__.test'>
>>> a
<class '__main__.test'>
>>> a.testy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    a.testy
AttributeError: type object 'test' has no attribute 'testy'
>>>
```

Comment: `a = test() ` `print(a.testy)`

Comment: You never instantiate your class.

Comment: So a acts as a pointer to the class, and not a member actual class, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function not accessing class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680221/python-function-not-accessing-class-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had done a mistake while creating objects, please find below differences:

```
class test:
def __init__(self):
    self.testy=0
def __str__(self):
    return self.testy

a = test()
b = test()
a.testy
       output: 0
```

What you have done:

```
c = test
d = test
c.testy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'test' has no attribute 'testy'
```

Explanation:

when you are creating `objects` for a class use `object = class_name()`

**https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 0):

You define your variable inside **init**, which is only called when the class is instantiated. For a longer explanation, I'd refer you to the first answer on the question you linked.